# VS2017: How to create Project From Existing Code in an existing solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I want to add a bunch of existing projects to the solution in Visual Studio 2017. Those projects aren't originally intended to work in VS, so I am using File --> New --> 'Project From Existing Code' to make them usable there.

VS creates a new solution for every project during the creation of "Project From Existing Code". Can I change it so it will add such project to the existing solution at the time of creation?

The process I am using to add created from existing code projects to the solution:

1. I initially work with VS solution (which can contain projects).
2. I create a new project  from my existing code (File --> New -->
   Project From Existing Code).
   VS builds up its specific project files as well as solution file in the new project folder, closes currently opened solution and opens newly created one.
3. I repeat for every project I want to include in one solution.
4. I reopen the solution I was originally working on in VS and I add the projects to the existing solution (native VS projects I just created).
5. I go to the each project's folder in File Explorer and delete solution in each of them to reduce the clutter.

Comment: It is busy-work, but it is the only option you have available.  Unless you tell us what "existing projects" means, VS doesn't normally hassle you much about projects that were created by old VS versions.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be:

1. Create a new solution.
2. Remove the project that was part of the template.
3. Import the existing projects one at a time (right click on the solution --> Add --> Existing Project)

Comment: That's what I do basically, I want to know how to add projects to the solution during conversion (the existing Code to the VS projects). I guess there isn't a simple solution for that and I have to do this manually.